# SQL Server : how to get the 1st or 2nd letter in a word?

Tags: sql-server

I have a bunch of UK postal codes as follow:

```
Sector
S1 1
RH16 9 
NP23 9
N81 1
```

This is at a Sector Level. I can get a District level by just taking the first part of the Sector Level code before the space. ie: "S1" instead of "S1 1".

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE(c.Sector, ' ','.'),2)
```

And the Postal Area can be found by just using the letters: ie:"S" instead of "S1 1" or "RH" instead of "RH16 9".

I can write a query where it takes the first letter or the second letter, but how do I get it so that I can get the first 1 or 2 letters before I hit a number?

The final result should look something like:

```
Sector                PostArea
S1 1                     S
RH16 9                   RH
NP23 9                   NP
N81 1                    N
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Sector varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('S1 1'),
('RH16 9'),
('NP23 9'),
('N81 1')

Select *
      ,PostArea=Substring(Sector,1,patindex('%[0-9]%',Sector)-1)
 from @YourTable
```

Returns

```
Sector  PostArea
S1 1    S
RH16 9  RH
NP23 9  NP
N81 1   N
```

Edit:

To trap Non-Digit Strings

```
PostArea=case when patindex('%[0-9]%',Sector)=0 then '' else Substring(Sector,1,patindex('%[0-9]%',Sector)-1) end
```

Answer (score 0):

`select SUBSTRING(Sector,0,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Sector))`